# Property of orthogonal projection onto a closed convex set in euclidean $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, convex-optimization, inner-products, projection

Let us consider a Hilbert space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ equipped with a dot product $x\cdot y = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}y_{i}$. Next, let $S$ be a convex closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $s$ be a projection of $x$ onto $S$.

First, from the property of orthogonal projection, it follows that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}s_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}s_{i}s_{i}
$$

Next, let $y$ be some vector from $S$. What is the relation between $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}y_{i}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}s_{i}y_{i}$?

Is it always
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}y_{i} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}s_{i}y_{i}
$$
?

Answer (score 0):

The difference in the two terms you are trying to compare is $$ (x - s) \cdot y = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - s_i) y_i $$
If $x = s$ (that is, if $x \in S$), then it is always zero and the two terms are always equal. If they are different, this can have any value by varying $y$. It can be positive by setting $y = x - s$ or it can be negative by setting $y = -(x - s)$.

Comment: wait... would $y=x-s$ belong to S?

Comment: Missed the fact that $y \in S$ but the point still stands. If $S$ is a ball centered at the origin, then some multiple of $x-s$ and $-(x-s)$ will be in $S$.

Comment: @LrM I also just realized that there is something you can say about $(x - s) \cdot (y - s)$ which is that $(x - s) \cdot (y - s) \leq 0$

Comment: well, the inequality in the last message is a property of projection onto any convex closed set. This is not what is in the question.